# Pgfplots: Plot reflection and transmission coefficients of the Finite Potential Well

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the reflection and transmission coefficient graphs for the finite square well, but I can't. Can anyone help me or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: coefficients]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Classe de documento --- %
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Linguagem e Fonte --- %
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % Idioma brasileiro.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Acentuação automática.
\usepackage{sectsty} % Habilita a alteração do tamanho da fonte em seções/subsecções.
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} % Define o tamanho da fonte nas seções para 12pt.
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} % Define o tamanho da fonte nas subseções para 12pt.
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} % Define o tamanho da fonte nas subsubseções para 12pt.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Formatação --- %
\usepackage{makecell} % Permite quebra de linha dentro de tabelas.
\usepackage{setspace} % Habilita alteração de espaçamento.
\usepackage{tabularx} % Permite alterar a largura das tabelas.
\usepackage{xltabular} % Permite realizar quebras de páginas nas tabelas.
\setstretch{1.5} % Espaçamento de 1,5 linhas.
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo.
\setlength{\parindent}{2cm} % Indenta os primeiros parágrafos em 2cm.
\usepackage{geometry}   \geometry{paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,textwidth=160mm,textheight=210mm,top=30mm,bottom=20mm,left=30mm,right=20mm} 
% Geometria da folha A4, esquerda e superior = 3cm; direita e inferior = 2cm.
\usepackage{microtype} % Melhora a justificação do texto.
\usepackage{quoting} % Habilita citação com mais de três linhas.
\usepackage{tocloft} % Habilita alterações no sumário.
\usepackage{titletoc} % Habilita alteração no título do sumário.
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Permite colorir células nas tabelas.
\definecolor{gray(x11gray)}{rgb}{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Modo matemático --- %
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} % Ambientes matemáticos.
\usepackage{braket} % Habilita a notação de Dirac.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Estilos do documento --- %
\pagestyle{myheadings} % Estilo myheadings.
\usepackage{tikz} % Habilita a construção de imagens vetoriais.
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} % permite fazer interseções em gráficos.
\usepackage{hyperref} % Habilita hyperlinks.
\usepackage{footnotebackref} % Habilita hyperlinks nas notas de rodapé.
\usepackage{chngcntr} % Numera figuras de acordo com a subseção.
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Permite a criação de ilustrações.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Outros pacotes --- %
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite} % Padrão ABNT para citação e referências.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin = *}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Inclusão de gráficos/figuras.
\graphicspath{{Figuras/}} % Especifica a pasta das figuras.
\usepackage{subcaption} % Inclusão de subfiguras.
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{nomencl} % Lista de simbolos
\renewcommand{\abstract}{{\centering \bfseries RESUMO}\par\null} % Formatação para o título do resumo.
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Insere a bibliografia no sumário.
% \usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc} % Ajusta a margem das notas de rodapé.
% \setlength{\footnotemargin}{12pt} % Indenta as notas de rodapé em 12pt.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% --- Pré-Textual --- %

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% --- Capa --- %%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[axis lines = center,
                    xlabel=$E/V_{0}$,
                    ymax=1.4, ytick distance = 1,
                    minor y tick num=0, xtick distance = 35,
                    minor x tick num=10]
                    \addplot[samples=500, domain=0:pi,
                    semithick, red] {(1+ 4*x*(x-1)/(sin(deg(3*sqrt(x))))^2)^(-1)};
                    \addlegendentry{\(R\)}
                    \addplot[samples=500, domain=0:pi,
                    semithick, blue] {(1 + (sin(deg(3*sqrt(x))))^2/4*x*(x-1))^(-1)};
                    \draw[loosely dashed] (axis cs: 0,1,0)--(axis cs: pi,1,0);
                    \addlegendentry{\(T\)}
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center} \caption{Reflexibilidade ($R$) e Transmissibilidade ($T$)}  \label{transm-reflex}
    \end{figure}

\singlespacing
\renewcommand{\refname}{\normalsize REFERÊNCIAS}
\centering
\bibliography{Biblioteca} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.